# asp.net 6 mvc view Modal and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

I am using asp.net 6 mvc.

In my view part i do have this button over here:

```
<div class="d-flex my-4">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-md btn-info me-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#task_modal">Generate Report</a>
</div>
```

that onClick of it it opens the folowing Modal:

```
<!--begin::Modal - Upgrade plan-->
<div class="modal fade global-modal" id="task_modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered mw-650px" id="task-modal-content-container">
    <!--begin::Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content rounded">
        <!--begin::Modal header-->
        <div class="modal-header pb-0 border-0 justify-content-end">
            <!--begin::Close-->
            <div class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-active-color-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                <i class="ki-duotone ki-cross fs-1"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span></i>
                <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <rect opacity="0.5" x="6" y="17.3137" width="16" height="2" rx="1" transform="rotate(-45 6 17.3137)" fill="currentColor"></rect>
                    <rect x="7.41422" y="6" width="16" height="2" rx="1" transform="rotate(45 7.41422 6)" fill="currentColor"></rect>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <!--end::Close-->
        </div>
        <!--End::Modal header-->

        <div class="mb-2 text-center">
            <!--begin::Title-->
            <h1 class="mb-3">@Model.Title</h1>
            <!--end::Title-->
            <!--begin::Description-->
             <div class="text-muted fw-semibold fs-5">
                Created By : @Model.CreatorName
            </div>
            <!--end::Description-->
        </div>

        <!--begin::Modal body-->
        <div class="modal-body scroll-y px-10 px-lg-15 pt-0 pb-15">
            <div class="mb-13 text-center">
                <!--begin::Title-->
                <h1 class="mb-3 meeting-title-element"></h1>
                <!--end::Title-->
                <!--begin::Description-->
                <div class="text-muted fw-semibold fs-5 meeting-description-element">
                </div>
                <!--end::Description-->
            </div>

            <form novalidate data-kt-path="SaveNewMeeting" 
            class="form flex-lg-row kt_glabal_form"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data
                  data-kt-load-data="true">
             
                <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" name="MeetingId" />
             
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-4 required">
                        <span>Next Meeting From</span>
                        @*<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle ms-1 fs-7" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" aria-label="Result within 12 to 48 hours" data-kt-initialized="1"></i>*@
                    </label>
                    <!--begin::Col-->
                    <div class="col-lg-8 fv-row fv-plugins-icon-container">

                        <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid kt_flatpickr_Time from-date-input" placeholder="Select a From Date" name="DateFrom" eltype="text">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-4 required">
                        <span>Next Meeting To</span>
                        @*<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle ms-1 fs-7" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" aria-label="Result within 12 to 48 hours" data-kt-initialized="1"></i>*@
                    </label>
                    <!--begin::Col-->
                    <div class="col-lg-8 fv-row fv-plugins-icon-container">

                        <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid kt_flatpickr_Time flatpickr-input" placeholder="Select a To Date" name="DateTo" eltype="text">

                    </div>
                </div>
               @*  <div class="row mb-3">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-4 required">
                        <span>Remark</span>
                    </label>
                    <!--begin::Col-->
                    <div class="col-lg-8 fv-row fv-plugins-icon-container">

                            <textarea id="remarksTextArea" class="form-control mb-2" data-kt-autosize="true" eltype="text" name="RemarksDescription" placeholder="Remark" data-kt-initialized="1" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; resize: none;"></textarea>
                            <div class="fv-plugins-message-container invalid-feedback"></div>
                    </div>
                </div> *@

                 <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-2 mx-2">
                    <!--begin::Button-->
                    <button type="reset" data-bs-dismiss="modal" id="kt_modal_new_target_cancel" class="btn btn-light me-3">Cancel</button>
                    <!--end::Button-->
                    <!--begin::Button-->
                    <button type="submit"
                            id="kt_ecommerce_add_category_submit"
                            class="btn btn-primary">
                        <span class="indicator-label">Save</span>
                        <span class="indicator-progress">
                            Please wait...
                            <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle ms-2"></span>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                    <!--end::Button-->
                </div> 
            </form>

            <!--begin:Form-->
            <!--begin::Heading-->
           
            <!--end::Heading-->

            <!--begin::Actions-->
           @*  <div class="text-center">
                <button type="reset" id="kt_modal_new_target_cancel" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-light me-3">
                    Cancel
                </button>

                <button type="submit" id="kt_modal_new_target_submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="indicator-label">
                        Save
                    </span>
                    <span class="indicator-progress">
                        Please wait... <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle ms-2"></span>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div> *@
            <!--end::Actions-->
            <!--end:Form-->
        </div>
        <!--end::Modal body-->
    </div>
    <!--end::Modal content-->

</div>
</div>
<!--End::Modal - Upgrade plan-->
```

In this modul the user can pick a FromDate and ToDate and on click of the submit button a new meeting will be created.

Now i do have this jquery for my date picker

```js
$(".kt_flatpickr_Time").flatpickr({
    //onReady: function () {
    //    this.jumpToDate("2022-01")
    //},
    altInput: true,
    enableTime: true,
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i",
    altFormat: "F j, Y H:i",
    //defaultDate: "today",
    minDate: "today",
    minTime: minTime,
    mode: "single"
});
```

that the user can choose the date and the time of the meeting.

Now the problem that i am facing is that after i click on the To Date and pick any date the From Date flatpickr is opening automaticaly so i am getting two field that i can choose a date in but i can only choose from the initial one.

How can i fix that beacause i am getting a lot of errors when i using this type of Modal in my view page.

I tried different things and i did a lot of research and i am still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't reproduce your issue in my side, here's my test:

[image]

According to the symptom, I think we might try to give an id to each of the datetime picker and init the datetime picker with ID selector but not the class selector so that we might avoid multi-select issue. Or we might [use the `range` mode](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#mindate-and-maxdate) instead of the `single` mode, so that we only have one datetime picker.

[image]
[image]

================     Update   ==================

I might reproduce your issue this time.

[image]

When we click the datetime picker, the corresponding calendar has the `open` class, but when we click anyplace of the calendar of the `to time`, it would add `open` class to the `from time` datepicker.

[image]
[image]

This time I kept all of the `class` inside your code and I see the unexpected behavior, I'm afraid it's a "Not compatible" issue and because I just removed some class indeed. I trust using the `range` mode could be a workaround which could save much time.

Comment: you will find that, if you remove the class in the `<div class="modal fade global-modal" id="task_modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">`, the datetime picker would work well.